# Higher-performance method do this type of insert from python?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, benchmarking

Given two arrays `hashes` and `table`, for each value in `hashes` I want to store the position of the element at the element's value's offset in the array `table`. Here is the naïve algorithm:

```
def insert_n(table,hashes):
    for x in xrange(len(hashes)):
        table[hashes[x]]=x
```

This is extremely slow. Psyco helps some here, but hardly.

Numpy has a solution:

```
numpy.insert(table,numpy.arange(len(hashes)),hashes)
```

But according to my benchmarks, this is still extremely slow for such a simple operation. Is there a faster way to perform this that can be used from python?

Some additional example code:

```
import numpy

from time import time

table_size=2**20

hashes_size=2**19

table=numpy.zeros(table_size,dtype=numpy.uint32)

hashes=numpy.fromstring(numpy.random.bytes((hashes_size)*4),
                        dtype=numpy.uint32)%table_size

t0=time()

numpy.insert(table,numpy.arange(len(hashes)),hashes)

print time()-t0
```

Comment: You're aware that if there are multiple instances of one hash, then the table will point to the last one only?

Comment: Yes, it's for a type of caching system where it's perfectly fine to trade off the higher speed for losing some of the values due to collision. Newer entries will assumed to be more probable cache hits anyway.

Comment: What is up with the edits on this question, and why don't you accept answers, OP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fast and simple (assuming table and hashes are numpy.uint32 arrays):

```
table[hashes] = numpy.arange(len(hashes), dtype=numpy.uint32)
```

You may want to compare the speed with this:

```
table[hashes] = xrange(len(hashes))
```

By the way, `numpy.insert` does not do the same thing as the for-loop you posted.

Comment: Completely right, I was using insert when I meant to use put (which is equivalent to your slicing assignment.) You got it.